# Kafka Camel Spring Boot AutoConfiguration is not picked up when multiple kafkaComponent beans are defined

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I'm currently using [this camel-kafka-starter maven dependency](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/kafka-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration) to autoconfigure my kafka camel component in Spring Boot.

If I add say, a setting like this `camel.component.kafka.configuration.linger-ms=20`. The camel kafka component picks it up in the route and I can see its config value in the log output.
e.g.

```
@Component
public class route extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file://target/inbox")
        .to("kafka:topic?brokers=localhost:9092");
    }
}
```

Now, if i define another camelKafkaComponent Bean, **it loses the autoconfiguration!** I'd expect it to maintain the settings defined in application.propeties...

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public KafkaComponent myKafkaComponent() {
    return new KafkaComponent();  //missing the linger-ms=20 i set in application.properties!
  }

  @Component
  public class route extends RouteBuilder {
     @Override
     public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file://target/inbox")
        .to("myKafkaComponent:topic?brokers=localhost:9092");
     }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to maintain the autoconfiguration by some setting e.g.

```
myKafkaComponent.useAutoConfig()
```

Ideally in my application.properties I'd have ~40+ settings that I would like to just transfer over to my user defined camel kafkaComponent. Is it necessary to create another Config class and map all those values defined in the camel docs? (with something like String @Value annotations)

edit:
I was looking at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot/blob/master/components-starter/camel-kafka-starter/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/springboot/KafkaComponentAutoConfiguration.java) and was also wondering if there was a way to call it inside my bean definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a bean of type

```
ComponentCustomizer<KafkaComponent>
```

which can be used to customize the kafka component auto configured by camel

Comment: but what if i want say, 3 custom KafkaComponent beans in my SpringContext, and each one needs different Customization e.g. threadpool & brokers etc... but share all common properties specified by the camel-kafka-starter autoconfig?  I believe their implementation won't allow other beans inheriting their config due to [this line](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot/blame/29d6f3e0ab03c297fc52be2ec181f495501eca5a/components-starter/camel-kafka-starter/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/springboot/KafkaComponentAutoConfiguration.java#L79)

Comment: if the properties youa re looking for are configurable at endpoint level, then you do not need to configure 3 different components i.e.:

    .to("kafka:topic?brokers=broker-1:9092")
    .to("kafka:topic?brokers=broker-2:9092")
    .to("kafka:topic?brokers=broker-2:9092")