# How do I Customize Predefined Camel Components?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm using a Kafka Component in the `camel-kafka-starter` dependency. 
In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60309688/kafka-camel-spring-boot-autoconfiguration-is-not-picked-up-when-multiple-kafkaco) I was recommended to use a "customizer". How would I use this in my spring boot application?

Comment: So you wrote an answer to your question ????

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Amongalen Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution would be to define the component in your SpringBoot Configuration file as such:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

   @Bean 
   ComponentCustomizer<KafkaComponent> myCustomizer(){
       return new ComponentCustomizer<KafkaComponent>() {

           @Override
           public void customize(KafkaComponent component) {
               //KafkaConfiguration config = new KafkaConfiguration(); //optional extra config

               component.setAllowManualCommit(true);
               component.setBrokers(brokers);
               component.setWorkerPool(workerPool); 
           };
       };
    }

   @Component
   public class route extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
           from("file://target/inbox")
           .to("direct:kafka_in")

           from("direct:kafka_in")
           .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "Generated : $simple{body}")
           .to("kafka:topic2")
           .log("[P-kafka_in] regular Producer");

       } 
    }
}
```

In addition to any config set in properties:

```
camel.component.kafka.configuration.retries=1234567
camel.component.kafka.configuration.request-required-acks=all
camel.component.kafka.configuration.enable-idempotence=true
```

The component would then flow into this customiser and be processed there.

Comment: Just to make sure, is that an actual answer and it wasn't meant ot be part of the question?